# Rails 4: How can I use "redirect_to" with AJAX to render a partial after uploading file(s)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, carrierwave, remotipart

I am using `carrierwave` and `remotipart` to handle an AJAX form where I upload an album of music and accompanying information to a website. After submitting the form, I would like to redirect the partial where the form was located to the newly created album's page. The form, located in `\albums\_new.html.erb` looks like this:

```
<h1>Add a new album</h1>
<div>
    <%= form_for(album, remote: true, url: {action: "create"}, html: {multipart: true}) do |f|%>
        <h2>Information: </h2>
        <div>
            <%= f.label :title %>
            <%= f.text_field :title %>
            <%= f.label :year %>
            <%= f.text_field :year %>
            <%= f.label :image %>
            <%= f.file_field :image %>
        </div>

        ...

        <%= f.submit "Add Album" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

The controller's `new` and `create` methods look like this:

```
def new
  @album = Album.new
  @album.producers.build
  @album.tracks.build
end

def create
  respond_to do |format|
    @album = Album.new(album_params)
    if @album.save
      format.js {redirect_to album_path(@album)}
    end
  end
end
```

The redirect currently only works when I submit the form without any file attachments. If I do try to include a file attachment, the upload still succeeds but the redirect fails and I get the following message in my console:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template albums/show,
application/show with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[],
:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}.
```

I have been able to implement a workaround where I simply call the same expression in `create.js.erb` that I do in `show.js.erb`:

```
$('#listen-window').html("<%= j (render partial: 'show', locals: {album: @album, tracks: @tracks, producers: @producers}) %>")
```

and write a `create` method as such:

```
def create
  respond_to do |format|
    @album = Album.new(album_params)
    if @album.save
      @tracks = @album.tracks
      @producers = @album.producers
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

Functionally, this code does achieve what I want. However, it does not make sense to me from a routing perspective. How would you write a more elegant solution?

Comment: why do you avoid the `format.html ` response?

Comment: I only want the result to render in part of the browser. I'm rather new to Rails development, but from what I understand, you need the `format.js` response to load using AJAX?

Comment: yes, `format.js` will be used for ajax response, but you also can have an html response with the json response `format.html` unless you don't want to load the html view

Comment: I have other things going on client-side in other partials while the user might be uploading files, so unless there's another way to not disturb them, I don't think I want to load the HTML view.

Comment: the have you tried `format.json { head :no_content }` this will not render the html view and it will give a 204 response to the ajax request, which is an empty response